# Why isn't this function ever being reached?

Tags: jquery, ajax, function

Why isn't the function with fadeOut ever being reached?  Every time the function runs it refreshes the page instead of using AJAX.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function deleterow(id){
if (confirm('Are you sure want to delete?')) {
$.post('delete.php', {id: +id, ajax: 'true' },
function(){
$("#row_"+id).fadeOut("slow");
});
}
}

</script>
```

Here is the html output by php:

```
<button onclick="deleterow('.$entry['rowid'].')" class="fg-button fg-button-icon-left ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span></button>
```

Comment: Check your javascript console for errors.

Comment: `id: +id` looks like the error.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the fact that your quotes are nested three deep?  i.e. " ' 'part that doesn't register' ' "  Maybe try escaping those quotes?

Comment: That's just how you would create the html in php, so i dont think so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its hard to say for certain without seeing the code/html that invokes the function but I assume this is attached to an `onclick` handler somehow. Therefore if you do not prevent the default action (following the `href` of the `a` tag) its going to refresh the page. You need to return false from the handler function or call`event.preventDefault()` from it.

I would use this markup instead:

```
<button 
  value="$entry['rowid']"
  class="fg-delete fg-button fg-button-icon-left ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span>
</button>
```

By encoding the rowid in the dom (in this case as `value`) we can access it in our functions without having to hard code it into the function call and keep the handler unobtrusive.

```
// pulling this into a full definition for clarity
// you could of course just use an anon function inside you $.click call
function handleDelete(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var $this = $(this);
   var rowId = $this.val();
   deleterow(rowId);
   return false;
}


$('button.fg-delete').click(handleDelete);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eBa7v/1/

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I am using a button onclick.  I thought about doing the preventDefault().  Do I have to pass the event through the functions parameters?

Comment: Yes, event handlers get the event object as their sole argument, you can however specify a hash of arbitrary data to be passed along inside that event object... post your mark up and i can give some examples.

Comment: @jcane86: See updates for how i would do it. Also pay attention to Madmartigan's comment on your question... looks like you have an error with the `id` post value your sending.

Comment: @TrevorMA prodigitalson's comment up here was meant for you I guess.

Comment: Opps.. yes it was... I need to quit multitasking :-)

Comment: @prodigitalson Man, this is a great example and everything is flawless on jsfiddle, but for some absurd reason, it does not work in my code...I will keep trying though..thanks

Comment: @TrevorMA: Then most likely you have a javascript error that is preventing it from running. Check out your JS error console as others have mentioned. Also use Firebug to inspect the ajax response form the server - if it doesnt return a success response code then your function will never been invoked because its only fired on success.

Comment: @prodigitalson After a lot of troubleshooting I realized it was the class name in the click event that wasn't matching up with the class in the DOM.  Strange.  Just another reason why I dislike web design. :(  Thanks for all the help!!